# Weird focus behavior in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

When I am in a text box typing something, if I hold down the Ctrl key, it will lose focus and when I release it, the focus gets back. If I press Shift while holding down Ctrl, the focus also gets back. Shortcuts like Ctrl+C also work.

The problem is when losing focus takes an action. When I am adding a bookmark in Firefox, holding Ctrl down will close the add bookmark popover and is really annoying.

I have tried some methods of debugging shortcut keys and couldn't understand what is causing my problem. I have also tried disabling my gnome shell extensions with no success.

What is causing this? How can I debug it?

Ubuntu 18.04.3. Gnome 3.28.4.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem until now. Try switching off *Show position of pointer when Control key is pressed* in *Keyboard and mouse* settings of GNOME Tweaks. It worked for me. When this setting is on, a flash around the cursor seems to steal focus while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed down.